# Showing a parameterized string for localization purpose

Tags: jsf, localization

Is there a way to have a parmeterized string in resource bundle? I need this as the order of nouns can be different in different languages.

For e.g. in my English bundle I will have

```
love_message={0} loves {1}
```

And my Latin translator will pick it up and do

```
love_message={0} {1} amet
```

And in my page I will have something like

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.love_message,John,Jenny}" />
```

(If this would have been possible)

So that my English translated page reads

```
Jonh love Jenny
```

And Latin page reads

```
John Jenna amet.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) instead of [`<h:outputText>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html). It can take those parameters as [`<f:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html):

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.love_message}">
    <f:param value="John" />
    <f:param value="Kenny" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: Thanks! i am assuming f:param will be taken in order they are written.